# How to replace a string by an URL in PDFBOX?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a text PDF with a string "Click Here".
How can I replace "Click Here" by a URL using PDFBox? 
Aka "Click Here" will be in blue and clickable after the replacement in the updated (or new) PDF.

Comment: I would probably start by doing some research, attempting some code based on said research, then posting a question when you have an actual problem.

Comment: PDF files arent actually meant to have real functionality like that - im guessing you could do some hacking with Javascript but thats ... ugly and kinda abusing the document structure, if it is at all possible - which is doubtful. Methinks you're using the wrong medium for your current task / goal, maybe you should consider creating a simple website instead. PDF files are **documents**, you dont actually *"do"* stuff within them, except for filling in form data or signing it - but thats pretty much about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [AddAnnotations.java example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddAnnotations.java?view=markup) from the source code download:

```
        PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
        borderULine.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
        borderULine.setWidth(1);

        PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
        txtLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);

        // Set the rectangle containing the link
        textWidth = font.getStringWidth("Click here") / 1000 * xscale;
        position = new PDRectangle();
        position.setLowerLeftX(...);
        position.setLowerLeftY(...);
        position.setUpperRightX(...);
        position.setUpperRightY(...);
        txtLink.setRectangle(position);

        // add an action
        PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
        action.setURI("http://pdfbox.apache.org");
        txtLink.setAction(action);

        annotations.add(txtLink);
```

You'll need to know the coordinates of your "Click Here" and the x scaling factor and the font, obviously. In PDF, (0,0) is the bottom left. 1 Unit = 1/72 inch. It is easiest if you generate the file yourself. If it is an existing file, you'll have to analyse the file with PDFDebugger or do some trial and error.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now how it works. I was naive, I thought there would be a PDF/ PdfBox function to give the position of the found text...

Comment: No there isn't (and you didn't ask). You can't even be sure that the string "Click Here" will be found in the content stream, it might also be like this:  `[ (Cl) -29 (i) -1 (ck) 30 (here) ] TJ`